# load whole html first then execute the php

Tags: php, jquery, html

i have this code here:

```
<div class="text-center">
    <img src="img/ford_lodding.gif" alt="Loading GIF" style="width: auto; height: 500px;">
</div>

<?php require 'php/loading.php';?>
```

and the php/loading.php is

```
<?php
if((!isset($_GET['id']) || empty($_GET['id']) && (!isset($_GET['email']) || empty($_GET['email'])))){
    header('location:index.php');
}
$email = $_GET['email'];
$ke = $_GET['ke'];
header('Location:turn3.php?id='.$id.'&email='.$email);

?>
```

yes i am creating a loading page, my question is how can i load the whole html first and then execute the php. i already tried [Load and display HTML first before PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26395645/load-and-display-html-first-before-php) and somehow it doesn't work and i am pretty new in ajax, so please explain it to me how does it work.

if you find out it is a duplicate question feel free to mark it and please give me the link to that question. thank you.

edit: i remove the ajax tag sorry

Comment: `my question is how can i load the whole html first and then execute the php` You can't. The pipeline of a page means that the PHP code has to run first to build the HTML output. It sounds like you need to amend the logic of your page to use AJAX to load the HTML you require.

Comment: you can use [jQuery.get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)`("php/loading.php", { id: 123 } , function(response) { ... }` to use AJAX and load the php file dynamically later.

Comment: so do you have any alternatives? so that i can make a loading page, without changing the rules?

Comment: As you said, AJAX is the only way. Btw. your if statement is unnecessary big... `!isset($_GET['id']` is 1:1 the same as `empty($_GET['id']` so don't check both...simply do: `if(empty($_GET['id']) && empty($_GET['email']))` will totally be enough. No reason to check ifs its empty and NOT set. Because when its not set, it will be empty.

Comment: lol i'm sorry for the !isset() and empty() ones i'm going to fix it soon

Comment: okay i am going to check the jQuery.get

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your `loading.php` to generate javascript code for redirecting to expected page

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  <?php
  if((!isset($_GET['id']) || empty($_GET['id']) && (!isset($_GET['email']) || empty($_GET['email'])))) {
    echo 'window.location.href = "index.php";';
  }
  else{
    $email = $_GET['email'];
    $ke = $_GET['ke'];
    echo 'window.location.href = "turn3.php?id='.$id.'&email='.$email.'";';
  }
  ?>

});
```

result

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 window.location.href = "index.php"
 // or
 // window.location.href = "turn3.php?id=15&email=my@ex.com"
});
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! it works, but i use different method

`<script type="text/javascript">
 window.location.href = "langkah3.php?ke=<?=$ke?>&email=<?=$email?>";
</script>`

in the current index, it work, i get the insight from your code thanks guess i'll mark this for the answer then

Comment: sip kalau begitu, sama2 gan.

Answer (score 0):

You could load the php file into a div after the document has been loaded with jquery eg:

```
<div id="mydiv">
</div>    
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#mydiv").load('test.php');
        });
    </script>
```

As mentioned in the commments - what you want is not possible

Comment: so i have to put the .php file in a div? and let the jquery load it? i tried it and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You could technically do the output first and then keep on continuing the other php logic running while you already show the loading.

```
<div class="text-center"><img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/12755/screenshots/1037374/hex-loader2.gif" alt="Loading GIF"></div>

<?php
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    //do things here -- login and stuffs
    sleep(10);
    echo "after sleeping and doing things for 10 seconds";
?>
```

However - you'll be better suited if you improve your logic to do it like the other answers suggest. In this way, based on your code - you wouldn't be able to redirect to another page since you've already made an output.

Hope this helps.

Learn more about OB (output buffering) flush here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php

Comment: thanks for your answer, it is informative for me and i just realized it yesterdat that you cannot do redirecting and output at the same time in php

Comment: please upvote if you find it informative, relevant :D